# iOS 15: Enabling "Configure in App" option for notifications

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, apple-push-notifications, ios15

In iOS 15, the notifications center got a bit of an overhaul. It's now possible to swipe a notification to the left and choose between some "Options". All of these options relate to the notification settings for the app that presented the notification.

What I have noticed is that some apps have an additional option that lets the user configure the in-app notification settings. I am having problems figuring out how to enable this option.

Here is an example of Snapchat which has the additional option, "Configure in Snapchat"

[Screenshot of example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oACSy.png)

I've tried reading up on Apple's documentation regarding UNUserNotificationCenter without finding anything that mentions this option.

*Note: This does not seem to be related to UNNotificationAction as that adds options when long-pressing the notification.*

Comment: Don't know for sure, but I would assume it's done by providing the `UNAuthorizationOptionProvidesAppNotificationSettings` option when requesting notification permissions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1395203/dan) was right!

When requesting authorization for push from UNUserNotificationCenter, `UNAuthorizationOptionProvidesAppNotificationSettings` should be added as an option.

```
var options: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .sound, .badge]
        
if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
    options.insert(.providesAppNotificationSettings)
}

UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: options) { 
    pushAuthStatus, _ in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        completion(pushAuthStatus)
    }
}
```

Then all you need to do is to add the following function in the `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` to handle what happens when a user clicks the newly added option.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_: UNUserNotificationCenter, openSettingsFor _: UNNotification?) {
    // Route to settings view
}
```

Comment: i am not getting that option, can you share your screenshot in your answer ?